# Is it possible to let the client choose the right translation of a page without scripting?

Tags: html

I have written a [website](http://fuz.su/go) for a local Go meeting in Berlin. It is translated into German, English and Chinese. Currently, I use the naming scheme `index.<lang>.html` for the three translations and a navigation bar on top to let the user choose.

Is it possible to use meta tags on the `index.html` (which currently is just a symlink) to let the user agent automagically redirect to the site with the right language if possible? I am interested in solutions that neither involve reconfiguring the server nor need java script to  be enabled although the first one might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP content negotiation to select a version that best matches the language preference information that the browser sends. So it is possible without scripting, but you need to set things up in the server for the negotiation.

However, this is not very practical, because the language preference information cannot be relied on. It is mostly based on browser defaults, since few users even know about the relevant settings in the browser, still less set the appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use meta tags on the index.html (which currently is just a symlink) to let the user agent automagically redirect to the site with the right language if possible?

No.

If you want automatic selection, then you need to pay attention to the Accept header in the request. That needs server configuration or scripting.

Without it, the best you can have is links to the translations of the document which the user can select manually.